# Will gRPC automatically start supporting HTTP/3 protocol or will coders/developers have to make changes?

Tags: grpc, grpc-java, grpc-python, grpc-node, grpc-c++

The question is self-explanatory. I'd like to ask if the libraries for C++, Python, etc. will of gRPC will automatically use HTTP/3 once it's introduced?

Comment: Given that it is a change in the transport layer, most likely the changes will be transparent to the user. You have a proposal in here: https://github.com/grpc/proposal/blob/master/G2-http3-protocol.md I guess there will be some new/changed configuration options on connecting though. In any case, hard to certainly know at this point.

Comment: I've confirmed it'll just be a line of code and we'll have minimal changes to make by someone working on this stuff. Thanks!